# OS X Downloaded File Warning

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, web-browsing

Example at bottom.

How does OS X apply this warning and what's the best way to disable it?

I'm a Web Developer and more than understand the risks of teh interwebs.

[image]

Comment: FYI, anyone can embed images. Just use the HTML: <img src="" />

Comment: @nathan-g Thanks, but I think I need just a little more rep before [that restriction](http://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user) is removed :)

Comment: @nathan-g Ah, nm, I leveled up!

Answer (score 2):

Use the Terminal and this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO
```

That will disable warnings completely after you restart the system. To reverse it, run it again with "YES" instead of "NO".

Or you can create a custom listing of safe files with the method described here:

[Custom assessment file for downloaded files](http://mymacinations.com/2008/02/06/changing-the-systems-default-settings-for-html-files-safe/)

Comment: How does OS X decide to apply the Quarantine?

Comment: -1 for admonishing the OP. It's not safe to assume they *didn't* check Google first because the same could be said of every question on the SE sites.